# Why can I not get this Microsoft Store snippet of code to work?

Tags: c#

Following various examples from MS and elsewhere, I have written this piece of test code...

```
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("4AEEEC08-7C92-4456-A0D6-1B675C7AC005")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IInitializeWithWindow
    {
        void Initialize(IntPtr hwnd);
    }
```

and..

```
    private async Task<bool> TestCode()
    {
        StoreContext Store = StoreContext.GetDefault();

        StoreAppLicense licence = await Store.GetAppLicenseAsync();

        bool trial = licence.IsTrial;
        bool full = licence.IsActive;

        IInitializeWithWindow initWindow = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)Store;
        initWindow.Initialize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);

        StoreProductResult App = await Store.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync();
        StoreProduct p = App.Product; // Title, price

        string title = p.Title;
        StorePrice price = p.Price;


        return true;
    }
```

And I call it with using

```
bool x = TestCode().Result;
```

It all compiles and runs, so I presumably have all the right usings and references added. But when run, the line:

```
IInitializeWithWindow initWindow = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)Store;
```

stops with the exception..

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext'
>   to type 'IInitializeWithWindow'

and I have no clue why.

- This is a C# program with a UWP wrapper creating an MSIX package.
- This seems to be a pretty standard block adapted from various examples from MS.
- Within VS 2019, I have associated the program with the store app.
- The 'trail' and 'full' variables seem to be populating correctly.
- I have called this from various locations, Constructor, random button, etc.

My questions...

1. Why does the cast throw an exception?
2. Is this an old way of doing things that no longer applies?
3. Does associating the package in VS 2019 to the store app make the call to IInitalizeWithWindow redundant?
4. How do I fix the code so that 'title' and 'price' populate correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heaps of head bashing and I finally have it working...

Considering that in the last few days there was not a combination/permutation that I did not try, I don't know really the logic of it working now, but anyway..

Within the UWP installer project I associated the project with the App in the Microsoft Store, then I removed the lines:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("4AEEEC08-7C92-4456-A0D6-1B675C7AC005")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
private interface IInitializeWithWindow
{
    void Initialize(IntPtr hwnd);
}

IInitializeWithWindow initWindow = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)Store;
initWindow.Initialize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
```

The rest is now working just fine. Funny as I had already associated the app with the store AND removed the offending lines. I must have done something just a little bit different this time!